# aws amplify react deployment throwing manifest syntax error

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am having issues after deploying React application using AWS amplify.
Couple of issues here:

1. I see that there was a reference to %PUBLIC_URL% in the public/index.html. In the documentation, it says %PUBLIC_URL% will get replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build. It doesnt seem to be happening. Not sure what build means here.
2. I replaced %PUBLIC_URL% with /. I seem to be getting `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`
   I tried adding `crossorigin="use-credentials"` as suggested in one of the forums, but that doesnt seem to have any effect.

I have sifted through reference to this error and none seem to be pointing to the solution.

Appreciate any pointers.

S

Comment: Looks like I have a similar problem as this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884235/aws-amplify-manifest-json-and-env-json-loading-index-html. I have added redirect rule as prescribed. The error persists.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. This worked for me:

1. Open Amplify console
2. 'App settings' > 'Rewrites and redirects', click 'edit'
3. click 'Open text editor'
4. paste this:

   ```
   [
     {"source": "/manifest.json",
       "target": "/manifest.json",
       "status": "200",
       "condition": null
     },
     {
       "source": "</^((?!.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$).)*$/>",
       "target": "/index.html",
       "status": "200",
       "condition": null
     }
   ]
   ```

Note: the redirect of the manifest MUST be before the index.html

Comment: Seems also important to redeploy the project version afterwards